# Bootstrap disbale dropdown button in nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a nav that looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
   </div>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown">
                <form method="post" action="">          
                    <select class="form-control" name="year" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Year</option>
                        <?php
                        $date = date("Y");
                        for($i = 2010; $i < $date+1; $date--){
                        echo '<option value="'.$date.'">'.$date.'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
                </form> 
        <form method="post" action="">
      </li>
         <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="january.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">January</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="february.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">February</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="march.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">March</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="april.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">April</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="may.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">May</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="june.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">June</a>
      </li><li class="dropdown">
        <a href="july.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">July</a>
      </li><li class="dropdown">
        <a href="august.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">August</a>
      </li><li class="dropdown">
        <a href="september.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">September</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="october.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">October</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="november.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">November</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="december.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">December</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The outcome looks good until I resize the browser. When it gets small it looks like this:

[image]

The button works fine but I would like to disable it, so it always shows the nav without pressing the button.

How can I do that?

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li.navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

Edit:

[image]

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/895xsgy1/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove following code in your HTML file:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
   </div>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-ex1-collapse">
```

and use like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
 <div>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown">
                <form method="post" action="">          
                    <select class="form-control" name="year" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Year</option>
                        <?php
                        $date = date("Y");
                        for($i = 2010; $i < $date+1; $date--){
                        echo '<option value="'.$date.'">'.$date.'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
                </form> 
        <form method="post" action="">
      </li>
         <li class="dropdown">.....</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Edit: **Updated** **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nuy3m8qr/1/)**

Try to add following code along with yours:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
        text-align: center;
        max-width:90% !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
        max-width:80%;
        display:block;
        text-align: center !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;           
     }
     .navbar-nav > li select {
        text-align: center !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked but now it doesn't fit anymore. The view from the other the one looked good. Check my edit.

Comment: can you create a fiddle demo.. It will be easy to find the problem. Anyhow, try removing " width: 100%;" from navbar-nav which is there in media query

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap lets you customize the width at which the navbar switches from collapsed to full. It's controlled by the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable in the .less source files.

If you're not using the less source files, you can download a customized version of the css here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ you'll need to search for `@grid-float-breakpoint` on this page and edit it.

For more information, see the documentation at
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: something like (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1)? And what does the - 1 mean? I'm also going to check the other link now.

Comment: In think to keep it from collapsing you would set `@grid-float-breakpoint` to `0`

Comment: Same resullt, the input field is out of the nav.